# wxPython: overload 1: argument 1 has unexpected type 'ScrolledPanel'

Tags: python, types, overloading

I'm trying to figure out how to change text in scrolled panel box  but for some reason it gives me this error.

```
File "/Users/adapterad/Desktop/daba-0/gdisamb.pyw", line 1089, in ShowSent
self.Sizer.Remove(self.annotlist)
TypeError: Sizer.Remove(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: argument 1 has unexpected type 'ScrolledPanel'
```

Here is code:

```
def CreateGlossButtons(self) :

    self.annotlist = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
    self.annotlist.SetScrollRate(20, 20)
    if self.vertical:
        annotsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    else:
        annotsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
    for (toknum, (token,selectlist)) in enumerate(zip(self.tokenlist,self.selectlist)):
        abox = GlossSelector(self.annotlist, (self.snum, toknum), token, selectlist, vertical=self.vertical)
        tokenbuttons.append(abox)
        annotsizer.Add(abox)
    self.annotlist.SetSizer(annotsizer)
    self.annotlist.Layout()
    return tokenbuttons

def ShowSent(self, senttuple, snum):
    self.senttext, self.selectlist, self.tokenlist, self.sentindex = senttuple
    self.senttext = self.senttext.strip()
    if self.isshown:
        self.sentsource.ClearSentence()
        self.Sizer.Remove(self.annotlist)
        self.annotlist.Destroy()
    self.snum = snum
    self.sentnumbutton.SetValue(snum+1)
    tokenbuttons = self.CreateGlossButtons()
    self.sentsource.SetSentence(self.senttext, tokenbuttons)
    self.Sizer.Add(self.annotlist, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    self.Layout()
    self.isshown = True`
```